# When did drop voicings (e.g. drop, 2 drop 3 etc.) become codified for guitar?

Tags: chord-theory, history

Nowadays the Drop 2 and Drop 3 7th chord voicings for guitar are well-known, especially in Jazz circles.  I don't remember hearing about these when I was reading *Metal Solo You Can't Play* Monthly back in the 80's.  I have Chuck Wayne's "[Guitar Studies - Chords](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0634002767)" book wherein he basically claims to have invented or at least independently developed this system decades ago (50's?) without ever calling it that (but he didn't publish until the 90's).  I have also heard that the "Drop __" nomenclature comes from arranging but can't substantiate this.

So my question is what were the first books / schools / artists to introduce Drop 2 and Drop 3 (etc.) voicings by that name as a thing to be learned and where did the concept originate?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know when it was first described but in Mel Bay’s Complete Johnny Smith Approach to Guitar on page 92 there is description of Drop 2 voicing vis-a-vis dominant 7 inversions.  My copy says it was published in 1980.